# Jenkins Agent node return is offline while it is online

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, build, amazon-ecs

I created a master jenkins in AWS and runing nods for build tasksI created with so my clud is bild from

1. I created with "Amazon EC2 Container Service Cloud" plugin an ECS agent template
2. Created with   "Amazon EC2" pluging to use an AMI

when I run the build I get that the node that Jenkins created (and runing) in offline
why?

this is the log

```
 > git checkout -f a2198a83470ed2e35fb4fa92ca04897b5e013d11 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Makefile edited online with Bitbucket"
 > git rev-list --no-walk a2198a83470ed2e35fb4fa92ca04897b5e013d11 # timeout=10
Triggering BO-App » Build » default
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
‘i-000eb8a582ba930fa’ is offline
‘i-01ada2700b0f561a1’ is offline
‘i-03f125f6ecdc82864’ is offline
‘i-0b33e8f0005807560’ is offline
‘i-0badf8ba4000b4a82’ is offline
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘EC2 (jenkins-ec2-agent) - jenkins-ec2-agent (sir-qq96c1sq)’ is offline
‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
‘i-000eb8a582ba930fa’ is offline
‘i-01ada2700b0f561a1’ is offline
‘i-03f125f6ecdc82864’ is offline
‘i-0b33e8f0005807560’ is offline
‘i-0badf8ba4000b4a82’ is offline
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘EC2 (jenkins-ec2-agent) - jenkins-ec2-agent (sir-qq96c1sq)’ is offline
‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
‘i-01ada2700b0f561a1’ is offline
‘i-03f125f6ecdc82864’ is offline
‘i-0b33e8f0005807560’ is offline
‘i-0badf8ba4000b4a82’ is offline
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘EC2 (jenkins-ec2-agent) - jenkins-ec2-agent (sir-qq96c1sq)’ is offline
‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
‘i-03f125f6ecdc82864’ is offline
‘i-0b33e8f0005807560’ is offline
‘i-0badf8ba4000b4a82’ is offline
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘EC2 (jenkins-ec2-agent) - jenkins-ec2-agent (sir-qq96c1sq)’ is offline
‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
‘i-0b33e8f0005807560’ is offline
‘i-0badf8ba4000b4a82’ is offline
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘EC2 (jenkins-ec2-agent) - jenkins-ec2-agent (sir-qq96c1sq)’ is offline
‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
‘i-0badf8ba4000b4a82’ is offline
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘EC2 (jenkins-ec2-agent) - jenkins-ec2-agent (sir-qq96c1sq)’ is offline
‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘EC2 (jenkins-ec2-agent) - jenkins-ec2-agent (sir-8qvee66n)’ is offline
‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
Configuration BO-App » Build » default is still in the queue: ‘EC2 (jenkins-ec2-agent) - jenkins-ec2-agent (sir-8qvee66n)’ is offline
‘Jenkins’ is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
‘i-0349259e6fbff9789’ is offline
BO-App » Build » default completed with result FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I checked the SG and added all jenkins ports
but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure Jenkins agent is up and running ([where to find agent](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/))
- Make sure EC2 Instance is in Running state.
- If it's in running state try restarting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).